# xHtml download file to hard drive

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Is it possible to download a file from my server directly to a user's hard drive? when I try to download a CSS file, my browser just opens the css file in a new browser (almost like Microsoft Word would). I want the user to have the *actual* css file though.

#### Code

```
<a href="Stylesheets/custom.css" rel="external">Download This File</a>
```

Comment: When you say 'directly to the user's hard drive', what do you mean? Without a download prompt? Cos you can't do that, for fairly obvious security reasons...

Comment: http://teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx

If you click on "download v whatever" .... it will automatically prompt you to save the file as it downloads it to your downloads folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force a download prompt, the simplest way to do it is to use some kind of server-side scripting language to modify the headers so they include `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.ext"`. This is very easy in PHP, but it really depends on what languages/facilities your server has available.

There are things you can do to the server configuration itself to force this as well - how you do it depends on the server you are running.

If you wanted to do it in PHP, here is a short example:

getcss.php (placed in the same directory as the HTML file with the link in it)

```
<?php

  if (!isset($_GET['file']) || !file_exists($_GET['file'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found');
    exit;
  }

  header('Content-Type: text/css');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($_GET['file']));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($_GET['file']).'"');
  readfile($_GET['file']);
  exit;

?>
```

Then your link would be:

```
<a href="getcss.php?file=Stylesheets/custom.css">Download This File</a>
```

Comment: @DavrRandom I get an error saying: "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/zxq.net/n/a/n/nanisolutions/htdocs/getcss.php:11) in /www/zxq.net/n/a/n/nanisolutions/htdocs/getcss.php on line 14"

Comment: Yeah, that's how you'd do it. Although it's best practice to never accept a file path as a GET parameter, because someone could get any file on your server that way. E.G. If you had /passwords.php I'd be able to just put that in and download the file. Best solution there depends on how many different files you want to download via this method.

Comment: @Evan: you can't have anything outputted to the page BEFORE a header() call. E.G. If you have even just a SPACE before the opening <?php, it will fail. If you copied his code word for word, make sure there's no spaces or any text above the <?php code.

Comment: :) Works now. Yes, i did copy your code letter for letter - I am terrible with PHP sadly.

Comment: @Benno I know, but I thought I'd start simple and cover that later ;-) - Evan, if the error message you are getting say it's on line 11 you must have some extra white space before the opening `<?php` tag, because the first call that would raise that error is on line 8. Make sure the opening `<` is the first character in the file. If you continue to have problems I'll put an actual `.php` file up that you can download and use.

Comment: @Evan, as Benno said there are more consideratins here as you have just potentially left a huge security hole in your web server, but how we prevent that depends on exactly what you want to do. If you want to continue this is chat I will be available to do so in 5 mins or so...

Comment: Simplest option in the regard of the security flaw is to maintain a list of actions->files if you don't have too many to download. Make the link ?file=custom and then in the PHP file, `$map = array('custom'=>'stylesheet/custom.css'); $file = $map[$_GET['file']];` (i.e. $map['custom'] is equal to 'stylesheet/custom.css') and replace all `$_GET['file']` with `$file`

Comment: @Benno That works, but the problem comes when you want to add another one and forget to add it to the file. For simplicity's sake I was going to suggest jailing the script to one folder - that way all you need to do to add another one is symlink to it.

Comment: Yes, I would like to chat with you! I would very much appreciate that.

Comment: Hi Evan, I was just going over the second scipt I sent you yesterday and realised there is still a security hole in it - please change the line `$download_file = "$downloads_dir/".$_GET['file'];` to `$download_file = "$downloads_dir/".basename($_GET['file']);` to fix it :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache and/or PHP, and are able to modify your server configuration, or (possibly, depending on restrictions) use a htaccess file, you need to set the Content-Disposition header to be sent from the server (or in a separate PHP file, if using PHP). Unsure what would be required if you use ASP, or no programming language..

This example from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
```

In your case would be:

```
// We'll be outputting a CSS
header('Content-type: text/css'); // if this doesnt work, try application/octet-stream instead of text/css
// It will be called custom.css
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="custom.css"');
// The CSS source is in custom.css
readfile('custom.css'); // http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php
```

This means you'd either have to make a PHP page with the above code in it, and link to that instead, or add something like this to htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*custom.css$">
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Update: scratch the htaccess thing. That'd probably make you download stylesheets that are trying to render on your page, unless you used a different filesmatch type condition, and had files you wanted users to download in an individual folder.

Comment: I will see if I am able to modify these things.

Comment: I just tested this and this is what happened: IE7/8/Chrome ignore the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header when they get it in answer to a request from a `<link>` element and render the stylesheet normally. FF3/4 don't give a prompt, and don't render the stylesheet. Don't have Opera or Safari to hand to test.

Comment: Haha, yeah I just realised that after I'd re-read the filesmatch statement... I was like... uhhh hmm lol that will mean the stylesheet probably won't render :p lol. It'd have to be a more specific condition/folder that the header was set for.